# Stop looping AJAX query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Using jQuery and AJAX, I've created a script that loops every second to refresh a console.

The page is setup like so:
`index.php -> console.php -> consoleQuery.php`

Where `index.php` is the main page, with buttons that can trigger multiple AJAX scripts and replace the body of `index.php` with the returned contents. One of the scripts being `console.php` and part of `console.php` includes the following script.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/consoleQuery.php",
        data: "",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#consoleBody").html(response);
        }
    });
    console.log("Console refreshed");
}, 1000);
```

This script calls upon `consoleQuery.php` to essentially update the body of the page and refresh it every second.

The problme is however, upon clicking another page thats parented to `index.php`
(for example `index.php -> home.php`)
the JS that is causing the loop still occurs in the background when `home.php` replaces the body of `index.php`. On top of this, triggering `console.php` again causes it to then refresh the console twice per second and so on if its clicked multiple times. Essentially the loop is running in multiple instances.

What I want to try and do is upon triggering one of the AJAX requests that doesn't request `console.php`, stop the looping script that is refreshing the body of the page.

Is there any way to stop the loop when accessing a different page? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you grab the timer ID:

```
var consoleRefreshTimer = window.setInterval...
```

then you can stop it with:

```
clearInterval(consoleRefreshTimer);
```

You probably want to clear it at every subpage AJAX request, and start it once you render the subpage that needs it. Even better, have subpages define `setup` and `teardown` functions, call `setup` just after you display it, call `teardown` just before you start the AJAX request for a new one. Or make an object for each page that will wrap this functionality in the main page. Quick and dirty example:

```
var subpages = {
  main: {
    url: "http://example.com/main",
  },
  console: {
    url: "http://example.com/console",
    setup: function() {
      this.timer = setInterval(function() { console.log("consoled!"); }, 1000);
    },
    teardown: function() {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  }
};

var getSubpage = (function() {
  var currentSubpage = {};
  return function(key) {
    var subpage = subpages[key];
    if (currentSubpage.teardown) currentSubpage.teardown();
    console.log("loading " + key + " (actually faking it with timers)");
    setTimeout(function() {
      currentSubpage = subpage;
      console.log("showing " + key);
      if (currentSubpage.setup) currentSubpage.setup();
    }, 500);
  };
})();

getSubpage('main'); // main is loaded
getSubpage('console'); // console is loaded; console timer starts up
getSubpage('main'); // main is loaded; console timer stops
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! The setup and teardown method didn't work because the `setInterval` function was called inside the console.php AJAX script. However using the method which created the variable and clearing the interval worked perfectly! Thanks for your help very much!